# XJC Generating Integer Instead of int

Tags: xsd, jaxb, code-generation, xjc

The following schema should be generating two primitive `int` fields in a `Value` class, but instead generates a primitive `int` for the **element** and [java.lang.Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) for the **attribute**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/test" xmlns:test="http://www.example.com/test"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="values">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element ref="test:value" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="value">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <!-- Is generated as primitive int -->
                <xsd:element name="element" type="xsd:int" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <!-- Is generated as java.lang.Integer -->
            <xsd:attribute name="attribute" type="xsd:int" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

I've looked through the [JAXB documentation](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/) for anything that says that attributes and elements may be generated differently and found nothing.

Can anyone explain this? Is there a fix to make the attribute generate as a primitive `int`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is the answer, but I had an epiphany while debugging my app.

The default multiplicity for an **element** in an XML schema is `1..1 (required)` where as the default multiplicity for an **attribute** is `0..1 (optional)`.

1. So, since the **element** is *required* and a primitive in Java has a default value (most likely 0), it makes sense to generate an `<xsd:element type="xsd:int" />` as a Java primitive.
2. Since the **attribute** is *optional* there is a possibility that it may be `nillable` which would not be possible using a primitive. The [java.lang.Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) is an `Object` and thus allowed to be `null`, so it makes sense to generate an `<xsd:attribute type="xsd:int" />` as an [java.lang.Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

If you make an **attribute** be *required* (`<xsd:attribute type="xsd:int" use="required" />`), it will generate as a primitive `int`. I haven't seen documentation by JAXB that explicitly says this, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist; perhaps I just missed it.