# Java int type from XSD

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XJC Generating Integer Instead of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270360/xjc-generating-integer-instead-of-int)

Need to generate entity class with primirive int field. But xml string like this

```
<xs:element name="RetriesCount" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" default="2"/>
```

generates class with Integer filed named 'retriesCount'. Using `xs:integer` causes generation with BigInteger type of 'retriesCount' field. Is there any solution to generate a simple Java int?

Comment: Although I'm not sure if that is really the problem, unless `minOccurs="0"` is the culprit?

Comment: @mellamokb That is my suspicion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your schema says `minOccurs="0"`, JAXB has to use a type that is able to represent a `null` value, which is why it uses `Integer`.  If you can change the schema to `minOccurs="1"` it will be able to use `int` instead.

Note that the `default="2"` doesn't necessarily do what you expect in XML.  In particular the bound property will only take the default value if there *is* a `RetriesCount` element specified, but that element has no value (i.e. `<RetriesCount />` or equivalently `<RetriesCount></RetriesCount>`).  If the `RetriesCount` element is completely absent the property value will be `null`.