# Apache CXF I don't want primitives

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I generate my proxy class via wsdl2java goal in maven pom.

Sample xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="homeNo" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Generated class has homeNo property with int (primitive type). I would like to "big Integer" Wrapper type. How to force it? One way is add nillable="true" but it is terrible and it not looks well in schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the translation to and from Java types with a bindings file.  For example, if you wanted to have all xsd:int elements bound to BigInteger, create a file bindings.xjb with the content

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
  xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <!-- use BigInteger instead of int-->
        <jxb:javaType name="java.math.BigInteger" xmlType="xs:int"/>
    </jxb:globalBindings>  
</jxb:bindings>
```

When you call wsdl2java, use the `-b` option to specify the bindings file

`wsdl2java -b bindings.xjb foo.wsdl`

This will cause XJC to generate an adapter class, probably named something like

`org.w3._2001.xmlschema.Adapter1`

Your generated objects will make use of this class with the [@XmlJavaTypeAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html) anotation.

You can also provide your own adapter methods using the `parseMethod` and `printMethod` attributes of `<jxb:javaType />`.

The [Customizing JAXB Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148613) section of the Java Web Services Tutorial provides more detail on what you can do with `<jxb:javaType />`.

Comment: nice sugestion! Thanks.

Comment: I added some additional comments to my answer, why `nilable=true or minOccurs="0"` is preferable.

Comment: `globalBindings` may be appropriate if you know you want to change the behavior in a global way.  Using `Date` instead of `XMLGregorianCalendar` is a common example.  You could also apply the binding to a specific element only, if there was a need.  There may be cases where you are not able (or do not want) to change the schema.  Understanding the implications of the binding decision is good (how nulls are handled is a good example), but I disagree that it is always a bad choice to change the bindings in this way.

Comment: This worked for me for the complex types classes, but did not work in the "...PortType" interface, which still contained primitives. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 2):

`nilable=true` or `minOccurs="0"` is the way to go, see [XJC Generating Integer Instead of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270360/xjc-generating-integer-instead-of-int)

I prefer this solution compared to the `globalBindings` because of following reasons:

1. `globalBindings` is a global switch that has consequences to all mappings. This may be preferable in some cases but it is rarely the case when you are working with Integers.
2. `nilable=true` or `minOccurs="0"` are adding semantic to the mapping. It says that the values are nullable. If these attributes are missing one must assume that this is not the case. That said, you only should use `Integer` instead of `int` if the value *is* nullable.
3. Using `Integer` instead of `int` is disastrous if you want to map a `null` Java value to the XML equivalent: What should be the outcome in the XML if in Java the value is `null` but this is not marked with the appropriate attributes in the XSD? This may generate invalid XML data.