# JAXB customisation getter/setter on optional attribute

Tags: java, jaxb

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270360/xjc-generating-integer-instead-of-int), optional attributes are generated as a Java primitive.
Perfect, it's exactly what i want.

```
<xsd:complexType name="applicationType">
   [...]
  <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

will be bound in :

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "id")
protected Integer id;
```

... BUT : the getter yet returns int ! (With boxing under the hood)

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

So, QUESTION is :
**How could i force the getter method to return Java primitive ?**

Thx a lot for your help
Regards

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If you have solve it, How have you done?

Answer (score 0):

Change your attribute in `<xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>`

If you don't use required this attribute could be nillable and in java object only `Integer` can rapresent this concept.

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270360/xjc-generating-integer-instead-of-int)

> Since the attribute is optional there is a possibility that it may be
>   nillable which would not be possible using a primitive. The
>   java.lang.Integer is an Object and thus allowed to be null, so it
>   makes sense to generate an <xsd:attribute type="xsd:int" /> as an
>   java.lang.Integer.
>   If you make an attribute be required (use="required"), it will generate as a primitive int. I haven't
>   seen documentation by JAXB that explicitly says this, but that doesn't
>   mean it doesn't exist; perhaps I just missed it.

Comment: See also https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-927 for `optionalProperty="primitive"`

Comment: Thx, Xstian
I have already tried this ;-)
First of all, the getter method still returns int (instead of Integer).
And, i have to be less intrusive as possible in XSD files.
I can only (if really necessary) change JAXB customisation at global level
But i would prefer to do JSXB customisation with jaxb2-maven-plugin.

The remaining point (seems odd for me) is that getter method.
How to force it to return Integer ?

Comment: @SylvainR Can you add the entire complexType? .. this behaviour is weird. Maybe also the jaxb2-maven-plugin configuration

Comment: @Xstian, i have browsed to jaxb2-maven-plugin configuration [xjc](http://bit.ly/1AWRuCA), but no specific things to force methods to return Java primitives.

Comment: @SylvainR Can you add all configuration and your xsd? in order to help you better :)

Comment: (cannot post more than about 590 characters, glurps... have to go deeper beyond Stackoverflow constraints)